# SX1262 Matching impedance

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, lora

I want to build a LoRa node from SX1261 which works on the frequencies of 868Mhz and I found at the manufacturer the following assembly ms I did not find more details on the different passive components.
if you can help me to build this node I will be very grateful.
[image]

Comment: It sounds as if you are not experienced in RF design. If so, more details about the passive components won't help much as many other aspects need to be considered for a successful circuit design. Why not use a ready made SX1262 module?

Comment: If you look at AN 1200.52 where you surely found this schematic, you will find component suggestions with values for 868MHz 2 pages down. Took me a few minutes to find and I've never used this part. So what's your actual question, why they picked those values?